# Mudança de Navegadores

Tags: css, bootstrap

Fiz meu site com bootstrap, e estou tendo uns problemas, no Mozilla o site é visualizado normalemnte, ja no Chrome esta distorcido confirme as imagens,
ALguém tem uma dica de como resolvo isso??

[image: Mozilla]

[image: Chrome]

```
<div class="menug">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#manu1">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered" href="#"><img class="img-responsive imgLogo" src="img/logo/efloorpqn.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarBorda" id="manu1">
    <div class="posicao">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="navbarBorda"><a href="#">Atendimento</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="navbarBorda"><a href="#entrar">Entrar</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Como Acessar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ideal Para Quem</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Funcionalidades</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Quero Conhecer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contratar</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contatos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Clientes</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div> 
</div>
```

```
                /*navbar*/
            .navbar {
                margin-bottom: 0;
                z-index: 9999;
                border: 0;
                font-size: 16px !important;
                line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
                border-radius: 0;
                padding-top: 25px;
                padding-bottom: 25px;     
            }

            .menug .navbar-brand {
                height: 80px;
            }

            .menug .nav >li >a {
              padding-top: 2%;
              padding-bottom: 2%;
              padding-left: 20%;
              padding-right: 20%;
            }

            .menug .navbar-toggle {
              padding: 5px;
              margin: 15px 10px 15px 0;
            }

            .navbarBorda .nav >li >a {
              border-color: #FFFFFF;
              border-style: solid;
              border-width: 1px;
              background-color: #222;
              margin-left: 15px;
              margin-right: 15px;
            }


            @media (max-width: 960px) {
                .navbar {
                    margin-bottom: 0;
                    z-index: 9999;
                    border: 0;
                    font-size: 16px !important;
                    line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
                    border-radius: 0;
                    padding-top: 15px;
                    padding-bottom: 15px;     
                }
                .menug .navbar-toggle {
                  padding: 5px;
                  margin: 10px 5px 10px 0;
                }

                .navbarBorda .nav >li >a {
                  border-style: none;
                  margin-left: 15px;
                  margin-right: 15px;
                }

                .menug .navbar-brand {
                height: 60px;
                }
            }

            .navbar-brand-centered {
                position: absolute;
                left: 50%;
                display: block;
                width: 160px;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: transparent;
                padding-top: 3px;   
            }

            .navbar>.container .navbar-brand-centered, 
            .navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand-centered {
                margin-left: -80px;
            }
```

Comment: Poderia fornecer o HTML e CSS do seu Menu?

Comment: Forneça mais detalhes pra gente, melhor ainda se tiver algo reproduzível (JSFiddle por exemplo)

Comment: Inclui o HTML e o CSS

Comment: @CarolKojima Não está de grande ajuda, pois ainda está totalmente diferente das imagens. Você não consegue passar uma simulação melhor do que você tem?

Comment: Simulei aqui https://jsfiddle.net/95vk3z9d/1/, se aumentar a tela da pra ver que o menu não fica certo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É que na navbarBorda você usou margin, assim leva o elemento para fora da borda. Trocando essa margin por padding dará certo, pois o padding é o espaçamento da borda para dentro. Ficando assim:

```
            .navbarBorda .nav >li >a {
              border-color: #FFFFFF;
              border-style: solid;
              border-width: 1px;
              background-color: #222;
              padding-left: 15px;
              padding-right: 15px;
            }
```